# Mysql query with <li> and <div> filtering

Tags: php, mysql, fetch

I have a product table that i am fetching with:

```
$query=mysql_query("select * from PRODUCTS left join IMAGES on IMAGES.IDI = PRODUCTS.ID"); 

 while($product = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
echo "<li><div><img>$product['PICTURENAME']</img></div></li>";
}
```

The problem is some products have 1 some have more than 1 image.. To list them as slideshow, while fetching should create that pattern;

```
<li><div class="jquery"><img>$product['PICTURENAME']</img><img>$product['PICTURENAME']</img><img>$product['PICTURENAME']</img></div></li>
<li><div><img>$product['PICTURENAME']</img></div></li>
<li><div class="jquery"><img>$product['PICTURENAME']</img><img>$product['PICTURENAME']</img></div></li>
```

Which means the products that have only 1 picture should be like;

```
<li><div><img>$product['PICTURENAME']</img></div></li>
```

And the other ones should be;

```
<li><div class="jquery"><img>$product['PICTURENAME']</img><img>$product['PICTURENAME']</img></div></li>
```

Because of JQUERY Slideshow, two `<img>` should be side by side inside `<li>` and `<div>`

The problem is "while" creates `<li><div><img></div></li>` each time.. For slideshow it must be like `<li><div><img1><img2><img3></div></li>`

Comment: So, what's the problem here?

Comment: how you inserted images in db please show

Comment: <img>$product['PICTURENAME']</img> ??

<img src="$product['PICTURENAME']"/>

Comment: The problem is "while" creates <li><div><img></div></li> each time.. For slideshow it must be like <li><div><img1><img2><img3></div></li>

Comment: Ruben Serrate i am using it like <img src="">. I just wrote like that to show the pattern

Comment: So put the <li> OUTSIDE THE loop! Doh!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
$query=mysql_query("select * from PRODUCTS left join IMAGES on IMAGES.IDI = PRODUCTS.ID");
while($product = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
$query_image=mysql_query("select * from IMAGES where IDI = ".$product['ID']);
if(mysql_num_rows($query_image)>1)
{
    echo '<li><div class="jquery">';
    while($image = mysql_fetch_array($query_image))
    {
        echo "<img>$image['PICTURENAME']</img>";
    }
    echo '</div></li>';
}
else
    echo "<li><div><img>$image['PICTURENAME']</img></div></li>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$query=mysql_query("select * from PRODUCTS left join IMAGES on IMAGES.IDI = PRODUCTS.ID"); 
$count=mysql_num_rows($query);

if($count==1){
  $product = mysql_fetch_array($query);
  echo "<li><div><img>$product['PICTURENAME']</img></div></li>";
}
elseif($count>1){
{
   echo "<li><div class='jquery'>";
   while($product = mysql_fetch_array($query))
   {
    echo "<img>$product['PICTURENAME']</img>";
   }
    echo "</div></li>";
   }
}
```